# Pandas Centric Way to Find Previous Value in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have an ordered pandas dataframe called **keys** containing columns `group_1`, `group_2`, ..., `group_N`, and `number`.

I have a second, ordered, pandas dataframe called **fill_in** having identical columns but different values.  For each row in **fill_in** I want to find the index of the corresponding row in **keys** that has 1) identical `group` values and 2) the largest value in `number` that is less than **fil_in**'s current `number`.  If a **fill_in**'s groups are not found in **keys**, it should output `np.nan`.  If the value in `number` is lower than any found within the group of **keys**, it should also output `np.nan`.

For a toy example, consider the following **keys**, **fill_in** and expected output:

```
keys = pd.DataFrame({'group1':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                     'group2':[5, 5, 5, 7, 9, 9],
                     'number': [19,35,61,5, 105,300]})
fill_in = pd.DataFrame({'group1':[1, 1, 2, 5],
                     'group2':[5, 5, 9, 9],
                     'number': [0,43.2,900.3,14]})
expected_output = [np.nan, 1, 5, np.nan]
```

I have solved this problem by pinching my nose and writing a `for` loop on pandas dataframes.  Not surprisingly, my solution is very slow.  Is there a way to solve this using pandas operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want merge_asof:

```
# make sure value columns are of the same type
keys['number'] = keys['number'].astype(float)

# output column is `index_y`:
pd.merge_asof(fill_in.sort_values('number').reset_index(),
              keys.sort_values('number').reset_index(),
              by=['group1','group2'], on='number',
             ).sort_values(['index_x'])
```

Output:

```
   index_x  group1  group2  number  index_y
0        0       1       5     0.0      NaN
2        1       1       5    43.2      1.0
3        2       2       9   900.3      5.0
1        3       5       9    14.0      NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `pd.merge_asof`:

```
key["number"] = key["number"].astype(float)

>>> pd.merge_asof(fill_in.sort_values("number"), keys.sort_values("number").reset_index(), on="number", by=["group1","group2"])

   group1  group2  number  index
0       1       5     0.0    NaN
1       5       9    14.0    NaN
2       1       5    43.2    1.0
3       2       9   900.3    5.0
```